# yum -y install not assuming yes in docker build

Tags: docker, dockerfile, centos7, yum

I'm trying to simply create a dockerfile that installs wget and unzip on a centOS image. This is the file:

```
FROM centos:latest

EXPOSE 9000

RUN echo "proxy=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:x" >> /etc/yum.conf \
    && echo "proxy_username=username" >> /etc/yum.conf \
    && echo "proxy_password=password" >> /etc/yum.conf \
    && yum update \
    && yum -y install wget unzip
...
```

When I run the build it resolves the dependencies just fine but it doesn't seem to be honoring the -y flag and assuming yes for any prompts:

```
Total download size: 61 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: Exiting on user command
Your transaction was saved, rerun it with:
yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx.2018-08-08.21-22.Q7f8LW.yumtx
The command '/bin/sh -c yum update     && yum -y install wget unzip' returned 
a non-zero code: 1
```

I've used the -y flag in this situation many times and have never had any trouble. It doesn't seem like this could be a caching issue but I have no idea what's going on. I also tried `yum install -y wget unzip` just for good measure but still no luck (as expected). I've searched stackoverflow but it seems like anyone with the same issue just wasn't using the -y flag. Any guidance would be appreciated because I don't know what could be going wrong with such a simple file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the `-y` on the `yum update`.

Also, you should split those commands out to separate `RUN` commands. In this case, it doesn't make too much difference, but splitting the `echo`s onto different lines will make it clearer.

You should keep the `update` and `install`s in the same command though

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run

Comment: Doh. Forgot there was a prompt during that as well. Do you mean splitting up the proxy stuff into one RUN and the installs into another? Or splitting up the update and installs into separate RUNs?